# Basic Linq and order by

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having trouble with a  simple linq query.

For example, I have a MS sql table with two columns.   Name and Date

in this table there are about 3 rows.

An example of the rows

```
Name          Date
SalesReport   10/1/2013
SalesReport   10/2/2013
Tax Report    10/2/2013
```

I want my linq query to group by "name", but order by date so the grouped field has the latest date and my results would look like

```
Name          Date
SalesReport   10/2/2013
TaxReport     10/2/2013
```

Here is the code I am using, but it will not to the order by properly.  I always get the same date regardless if I change the ascending or descending attribute.

```
Dim List = From w In db.reports
                Order By w.Date Descending
                Group By Name = w.Name Into g = Group
                Select g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you have is that you're not actually grouping your data by maximum date properly. All your current `Order By` is doing is ordering the data as it goes *in* to the grouping, not on the way out.

What you need to do is manipulate the data with a grouping, and return the name and the maximum date (as you would with a SQL GROUP BY clause):

```
Dim List = From w In db.reports
            Group w By Name = w.Name Into g = Group
            Select Name = Name, [Date] = g.Max(Function(p) p.Date)
            Order By Name
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, is it possible to prevent from using an anonymous type?  Originally this was a Linq entity that was being passed?

Comment: @jdross Yes, there's no reason (that I know of) why you can't reuse your existing type. Just substitute the `Select Name = Name ...` for `Select New MyObject With ...`. You'll then end up with an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` as a result.